# Mapping two tables with multiple values in one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to map two tables dynamically that have data like below and what kind of result I want is also posted there. Please help me with how I can get this result.

TABLES:

```
CREATE TABLE #A
(
    NAME VARCHAR(10),
    NUMBER INT,
    ID VARCHAR(5)
)

INSERT INTO #A VALUES ('JOHN', 20, 'J10')
```

```
+--------+----------+------------+
|NAME    |  NUMBER  |   ID       |
+--------+----------+------------+
|JOHN    |  20      |   J10      |
|MIKE    |  2       |   M5       |
+--------+----------+------------+
```

```
CREATE TABLE #B
(
    PRODUCT VARCHAR(10),
    NAME VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO #B 
VALUES ('APPLE', 'JOHN, HARRY'),
       ('ORANGE', 'JOHN,MIKE'),
       ('MANGO', 'JOHN, KATTY, ALEX')
```

```
+--------+------------------+
|PRODUCT |NAME              |
+--------+------------------+
|APPLE   |JOHN, HARRY       |
|ORANGE  |JOHN,MIKE         |
|MANGO   |JOHN, KATTY, ALEX |
+--------+------------------+
```

```
SELECT * FROM #A
SELECT * FROM #B
```

Result:

```
+--------+-----------+-----------+----------+
|NAME    |  NUMBER   |  ID       | PRODUCT  |   
+--------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| JOHN   |  20       |  J10      | APPLE    |
| JOHN   |  20       |  J10      | ORANGE   |
| JOHN   |  20       |  J10      | MANGO    |
| MIKE   |   2       |  M5       | ORANGE   |
+--------+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: You don't appear to be adding row "Mike" in your sample data. And why are you storing data as comma separated strings? The defeats the purpose of using a relational database, and causes you this exact problem. Store the data correctly normalised and you won't have this issue.

Comment: there are thousands of data like this and I need to map it. I have cross join the tables like below: SELECT * FROM #A
CROSS JOIN
#B
WHERE #B.NAME LIKE '%JOHN%' AND #A.NAME = 'JOHN'. hare I am getting only JHON'S data but in like operator If will be able to use dynamical script instead of using name JOHN. then I will get the right answer. but I don't know how to write the script.

Comment: I can't stress enough how important normalizing data is. You have violated 1NF by shoving multiple values into a single tuple. If your data design was properly normalized the query would almost write itself because it is easy.

Comment: [edit] your attempt into your question, and please correct your data so that its consistent

Comment: Thank you, Dale K. Actually I want to normalize the data that's why I need to separate those data. actually, I need to put those two tables' data in one table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that fixing the design is part of the solution here. But given the data as posted you have to jump through some ugly hurdles to overcome the denormalized design. That being said here is one way to get the desired output from the sample provided.

```
CREATE TABLE #A
(
    NAME VARCHAR(10),
    NUMBER INT,
    ID VARCHAR(5)
)

INSERT INTO #A VALUES ('JOHN', 20, 'J10')
    , ('MIKE', 2, 'M5')

CREATE TABLE #B
(
    PRODUCT VARCHAR(10),
    NAME VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO #B 
VALUES ('APPLE', 'JOHN, HARRY'),
       ('ORANGE', 'JOHN,MIKE'),
       ('MANGO', 'JOHN, KATTY, ALEX')

select a.NAME
    , a.NUMBER
    , a.ID
    , b.PRODUCT
from #A a
join
(
    select x.name
        , b.PRODUCT
    from #B b
    cross apply(select trim(value) from string_split(b.NAME, ',')) x(name)
) b on b.NAME = a.NAME
order by a.NAME
    , a.NUMBER
    , a.ID
    , b.PRODUCT

drop table #A
drop table #B
```

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for exact this answer. appreciate it.

Comment: If this answer solves your problem you should consider accepting it as the answer. That way others know you have a solution.

Comment: sorry I was unaware of it. Thank you again.